# How to prevent list view in catalog

Tags: magento-1.9, grid-layout, list-view

I use grid view in my store, and have already removed the option to switch to list view. However, Google has indexed a large amount of list view pages and keep on sending users to this view.

Is it possible to automatically switch to grid view if list view is detected?

Magento version: 1.9.2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In **Backend**

Go to `System-> configuration-> Catalog-> Frontend-> ListMode-> Select List Only`

Comment: I have this setting in admin, but this only prevents users from being able to change. However when Google already has indexed a page with **?mode=list** the list mode will still show. When this happens I would like Magento to overrule the ?mode=list setting so that it displays grid view instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set below product list mode from admin.

> "Grid Only"
>
> "List Only"
>
> "Grid (default) / List"
>
> "List (default) / Grid"

```
System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Catalog >> Frontend >> List Mode.
```

Comment: I have this setting in admin, but this only prevents users from being able to change. However when Google already has indexed a page with **?mode=list** the list mode will still show. When this happens I would like Magento to overrule the ?mode=list setting so that it displays grid view instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution:

I copied /template/catalog/product/list.phtml into my theme, and changed line 45 from `<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid': ?>` to 
`<?php if($this->getMode()=='grid' || $this->getMode()=='list'): ?>` and removed line 46 to 152 where the code for list mode was. In this way both modes will display as grid.

-Espen

Comment: First copy list.phtml from base/default to your_theme/default then edit list.phtml file of your theme folder only